# Monotonic interpolation between 5 points

Tags: interpolation, monotone-functions

For a problem in my research, I found myself looking for an interpolant function between five points: $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, $(x_3,y_3)$, $(x_4,y_4)$, and $(x_5,y_5)$. These points are monotonically increasing, and I need the interpolant to also be monotonic. I know I could achieve this with a piecewise monotonic cubic interpolation, but due to details of my implementation, I need this to be a single, non-piecewise function. After trying a bunch of functional forms that *technically* have enough parameters to capture these points, I wasn't able to come up with anything that had a closed-form solution in terms of the $(x_i,y_i)$ coordinates.

**Potential simplifications**

- For my particular application, I know that the points follow the form: $(x_1,-1)$, $(x_3-\delta,-y_4)$, $(x_3,0)$, $(x_3+\delta,y_4)$, $(x_5,1)$. So there's some amount of symmetry with the middle points, but not the end points.
- While I would ideally like to avoid a piecewise definition, a piecewise definition would be acceptable if the coefficients of the piecewise curves could be easily written in closed-form. In all honesty, this will eventually have to be implemented in Fortran77 running in an environment without access to external packages, and I really don't want to have to write very complicated code since it's a painful enough language as it is!

Comment: "but due to details of my implementation, I need this to be a single, non-piecewise function" sounds totally not convincing. Your points should be parameters of the interpolating function. Then nothing stops the latter from being implemented piecewise.

Comment: @KurtG., yes, it's certainly not explicitly necessary to have it be non-piecewise, but it would simplify the implementation a lot. As you can see in my note at the end of my response, I have to implement this in a very old software package using Fortran77 without access to any external libraries. As such, a piecewise definition is OK if necessary, but not ideal since it will add more complexity whenever I need to use this function, calculate it's derivatives, etc. I'll admit the word "need" was perhaps a bit strong ... maybe "strongly prefer" is better.

Comment: What is an example of a "single, non-piecewise" function that is acceptable for you? How will it know when the points $(x_1,y_1),...,(x_5,y_5)$ change? Even `Fortran77` should know what an `if` statement is making it possible to implement that function piecewise. I don't get what the problem is .

Comment: Yes, as I said, a piecewise function is possible, but will just add complexity. It's not impossible, obviously, but a simpler format is more ideal. 

For example, if we take the simpler case where the points are antisymetric about the third point (i.e., $x_4=2x_3-x_2$, $y_4=2y_3-y_2$, $x_5=2x_3-x_1$, and $y_5=2y_3-y_1$) then a valid form would be 

$$f(x) = y_3 - (y_1-y_3) \frac{Z^A-1}{Z^A+1}$$
where:
$$Z = \frac{x_1-X}{X + x_1 - 2x_3}$$$$A = \frac{\log\left(\frac{y_1-y_2}{y_1+y_2-2y_3}\right)}{\log\left(\frac{x_1-x_2}{x_1+x_2-2x_3}\right)} $$